# Image classification, network not learning anything

Tags: python, optimization, pytorch, loss-function, image-classification

So i am deshuffleing images, where they have each 4 corners at a random possition.

```
EPOCHS = 5
activation_function = nn.LeakyReLU()

LossList, AccuracyList, tllist,trlist,bllist,brlist,= [], [], [], [], [], []

model = MyModel(1, activation_function).to("cuda")

optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters())
loss_objective = nn.MSELoss()

for epoch in range(EPOCHS):
    
    model.train()

    for x, y in training_generator:
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        predictions = model(x)
        loss = loss_objective(predictions.to("cuda"),y.type(torch.FloatTensor).to("cuda"))
        loss.backward()
        LossList.append(loss.item())
        optimizer.step()
    with torch.no_grad():
        
        model.eval()
        tl,tr,bl,br,acc = model.evaluate(test_generator)
        AccuracyList.append(acc)
        tllist.append(tl)
        trlist.append(tr)
        bllist.append(bl)
        brlist.append(br)


    if epoch % 10 == 0 and epoch != 0: clear_output()

    print(
    f'Epoch {epoch+1}, \n '
    f'Loss: {LossList[-1]}, \n '
    f'Full Accuracy: {AccuracyList[-1]}, \n '
    f'Top left Accuracy: {tllist[-1]}, \n '
    f'Top right Accuracy: {trlist[-1]}, \n '
    f'Bottom left Accuracy: {bllist[-1]}, \n '
    f'Bottom right Accuracy: {brlist[-1]}'
    
    )
    print("-"*50)
```

The problem i have is that the model(VGG-11 with Batch Normalization after the convolutional layers) does not learn anything, and the accuracy stays at around 4% for correct full image, and 25% for each corner. The size of predictions is (batch_size, 4) and for labels its the same, with inegers between 0-3.

I think the problem is with how i'm suppose to make the model learn anything. Here is the model:

```
# @title Define model

class MyModel(nn.Module):
  def __init__(self, n_c, ActFunc):
    super(MyModel, self).__init__()


    self.layer1 = nn.Sequential(
        nn.Conv2d(3, 64, 3, padding=1),
        nn.BatchNorm2d(64),
        ActFunc,
        nn.MaxPool2d(2, 2)
    )

    self.layer2 = nn.Sequential(
        nn.Conv2d(64, 128, 3, padding=1),
        nn.BatchNorm2d(128),
        ActFunc,
        nn.MaxPool2d(2, 2)
    )

    self.layer3 = nn.Sequential(
        nn.Conv2d(128, 256, 3, padding=1),
        nn.BatchNorm2d(256),
        ActFunc
    )

    self.layer4 = nn.Sequential(
        nn.Conv2d(256, 256, 3, padding=1),
        nn.BatchNorm2d(256),
        ActFunc,
        nn.MaxPool2d(2, 2)
    )

    self.layer5 = nn.Sequential(
        nn.Conv2d(256, 512, 3, padding=1),
        nn.BatchNorm2d(512),
        ActFunc
    )

    self.layer6 = nn.Sequential(
        nn.Conv2d(512, 512, 3, padding=1),
        nn.BatchNorm2d(512),
        ActFunc,
        nn.MaxPool2d(2, 2)
    )

    self.layer7 = nn.Sequential(
        nn.Conv2d(512, 512, 3, padding=1),
        nn.BatchNorm2d(512),
        ActFunc
    )

    self.layer8 = nn.Sequential(
        nn.Conv2d(512, 512, 3, padding=1),
        nn.BatchNorm2d(512),
        ActFunc,
        nn.MaxPool2d(2, 2)
    )

    self.layer9 = nn.Sequential(
        nn.Conv2d(512, 512, 3, padding=1),
        nn.BatchNorm2d(512),
        ActFunc
    )

    self.layer10 = nn.Sequential(
        nn.Conv2d(512, 512, 3, padding=1),
        nn.BatchNorm2d(512),
        ActFunc,
        nn.MaxPool2d(2, 2),
        nn.Flatten()
    )

    self.layer11 = nn.Sequential(
        nn.Linear(512, 4096),
        ActFunc
    )

    self.layer12 = nn.Sequential(
        nn.Linear(4096, 4096),
        ActFunc
    )

    self.layer12 = nn.Sequential(
        nn.Linear(4096, 4),
        ActFunc
    )



  def forward(self, x):
    l1 = self.layer1(x)
    l2 = self.layer2(l1)
    l3 = self.layer3(l2)
    l4 = self.layer4(l3)
    l5 = self.layer5(l4)
    l6 = self.layer6(l5)
    l7 = self.layer7(l6)
    l8 = self.layer8(l7)
    l9 = self.layer9(l8)
    l10 = self.layer10(l9)
    l11 = self.layer11(l10)
    l12 = self.layer12(l11)
    out = torch.argsort(l12).type(torch.FloatTensor).requires_grad_()
      

    return out

  def evaluate(self, test_generator):
      batchfullacc = 0
      batchacc = 0
      for images, labels in test_generator:
          predictions = self.forward(images)
          batchacc += (predictions.to("cuda") == labels).sum(dim=0)
          batchfullacc += (predictions.to("cuda") == labels).all(dim=1).sum()
      tl,tr,bl,br = batchacc/len(x_te)
      acc = batchfullacc/len(x_te)

      return tl,tr,bl,br,acc
```

The training set is on 2500 images. The output i get is(this is only on 5 epochs, but nothing changes with more epochs):

```
Epoch 5, 
 Loss: 2.5899999141693115, 
 Full Accuracy: 0.042250003665685654, 
 Top left Accuracy: 0.2522500157356262, 
 Top right Accuracy: 0.2407500147819519, 
 Bottom left Accuracy: 0.25475001335144043, 
 Bottom right Accuracy: 0.25600001215934753
--------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Maybe you should explain more about what exactly you want to do and what kind of output you want to have.

Comment: But if what you want to do is sort a bunch of images, then it's basically a classification problem. You can't just have the model predict integer 0-3